# Мониторинг загрузки файлов

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Есть ли возможность мониторить загрузку файлов? Например -

```js
var style_css = 'css/syle.css';
style_css.onload(function() {
    console.log('css loaded');
});
```

```js
var js = 'js/java.js';
js.onload(function() {
    console.log('js loaded');
});
```

Есть ли что-то подобное?
Может на `php`, `js`, `html`, `ajax` или каком-то другом языке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
load('style.css');
load('script.js');
```

```js
function load(url) {

    if(url.match(/.js/)) {
        content = document.createElement('script');
        content.type = 'text/javascript';
        content.src = url;
    }

    if(url.match(/.css/)) {
        content = document.createElement('link');
        content.rel = 'stylesheet';
        content.type = 'text/css';
        content.href = url;
    }

    document.body.appendChild(content);
    content.onerror = function() { console.log(url, 'not exist'); }
    content.onload = function() { console.log(url, 'loaded'); }
}
```

---

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'
onload="console.log(this.href, 'loaded');">

<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'
onload="console.log(this.src, 'loaded');"></script>
```

Comment: Да, для динамической загрузки, тоже отличный вариант

Comment: Тоже хороший вариант. Спасибо!

Comment: Простите, а какой вариант лучше? Первый, вроде, адаптивней... Или мне кажется? Спасибо.

Comment: @Brave_Lime, если нужно лишь сообщить в консоле, то коненчо проще вывести в html событие. `<script onload='console.log(this)'>`

Comment: @Doofy Ну задача стоит в:  "При загрузке определенного файла - происходит (при помощи `jQuery`) изменение в `html` разметке"... Я ведь могу сделать  `<script onLoad="some_function();" src="https:.."></script>` Нет?

Comment: @Brave_Lime, тогда, я думаю, необходимо использовать функцию и внедрение в конце документа. А на jquery, вроде, есть метод `$.getScript()` [jquery.getscript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

Comment: @Brave_Lime, `onload="some_function();"` сработает

Comment: @Doofy Спасибо большое! (Но вот только, как тогда быть с сss'ом?... если же написать ` <script onLoad="some_function();" src="style.css"></script>` оно его не считет) :(

Comment: @Brave_Lime, `<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css' onload="console.log(this.href, 'loaded');">`

Comment: @Doofy ♥  Спасибо!!

Answer (score 3):

Можно!

```html
<script onLoad="alert(this.src + ' загружен');" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Можно написать какую либо функцию, и выполнять её, тогда:

```html
<script>
  function onLoadHandler(obj) {
    alert(obj.src + ' загружен');
  }
</script>

<script onLoad="onLoadHandler(this);" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Круто, спасибо огромное!!